# Javascript only loads after refresh (Squarespace)

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I have a javascript running on a squarespace site, but it only seems to work after the page has been refreshed once.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.markdown-block .sqs-block-content h2').addClass('ui-closed').css('cursor','pointer');
    $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h2").nextUntil("h2").slideToggle();
    $(".markdown-block .sqs-block-content h2").click(function() {
      
      $(this).nextUntil("h2").slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass('ui-closed ui-open');
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you asked squarespace for help? They're normally pretty good.

Comment: debugging 101: browser **developer** tools console - check for errors in it - report said errors, or use the info to debug your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript only being called once in Squarespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492245/javascript-only-being-called-once-in-squarespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Squarespace, when your custom Javascript only works after a page refresh, it most likely has to do with [Squarespace's AJAX loading](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000253288-Ajax-loading):

> Occasionally, Ajax may conflict with embedded custom code or anchor
> links. Ajax can also interfere with site analytics, logging hits on
> the first page only.

You may be able to disable AJAX for your template. Or, see the other approaches outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493314#54493314